# Conversion of color image to 8bit grayscale

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application which is suppose to operate on grayscale images. I'm having troubles with conversion input image to 8bit grayscale one. I wrote method that is suppose to convert input image to 8bit one but it's output doesn't even remotely look like grayscale image.

```
    private Bitmap ConvertToGrayScale(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Int32 bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
        if (bytesPerPixel == 1)
            return bitmap;            

        Bitmap grayscaleBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height,
            PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Byte[] pixelData = GetPixelData(bitmap);
        Byte[] grayScalePixelData = new byte[grayscaleBitmap.Width * grayscaleBitmap.Height];

        for (int i = 0; i < grayScalePixelData.Length; i++)
        {
            var pixelValue = (Byte)
                    (pixelData[i * bytesPerPixel] * 0.3 + pixelData[i * bytesPerPixel + 1] * 0.59 +
                     pixelData[i * bytesPerPixel + 2] * 0.11);

            grayScalePixelData[i] = pixelValue;
        }

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, grayscaleBitmap.Width, grayscaleBitmap.Height);
        BitmapData grayscaleBitmapData = grayscaleBitmap.LockBits(rectangle, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            grayscaleBitmap.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr pointer = grayscaleBitmapData.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(grayScalePixelData, 0, pointer, grayScalePixelData.Length);
        grayscaleBitmap.UnlockBits(grayscaleBitmapData);
        grayscaleBitmap.Save(@"D:\gray.jpg");

        return grayscaleBitmap;
    }
```

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You used `PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed`. That implies you need to supply a color table. Use the Palette property to do so. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.palette.aspx

Comment: Also, you do realize that Bitmap.Save("gray.jpg") will actually save a png file, right?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten this Bitmap.Save is used only for testing purposes. I will try to implement color table and see if it works.